# How can I get DateRangePicker to render calendars on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

When I render this in webpack-dev-server, the calendar doesn't render on click.

[image]

If I try to change the date manually, I get an error:

`DateSelection.js?f52c:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendarFocus' of null`

SingleDatePicker seems to work just fine, but not DateRangePicker. What can I do to render the calendar correctly on click?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import moment from 'moment';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-dates';
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

class DateSelection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment(),
      endDate: moment(),
      calendarFocus: 'startDate',
    }
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  };

  onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {
    this.setState(() => ({ startDate, endDate }));
  };

  onFocusChange({ calendarFocus }) {
    this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocus }));
  };

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <DateRangePicker
          startDate={this.state.startDate}
          startDateId="startDate"
          endDate={this.state.endDate}
          endDateId="endDate"
          onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange}
          focusedInput={this.state.calendarFocus}
          onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
        />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render((
  <DateSelection/>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Other details:

- react 16.2.0
- react-dates 16.3.5
- webpack 3.10.0
- webpack-dev-server 2.11.1

Also, as an aside, I can't seem to find the current docs of react-dates. A lot of places link me to [this storybook](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), but it seems some information is missing. For example, the Description column here is blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `calendarFocus` to `null` in the constructor.

And Change

```
onFocusChange({ calendarFocus }) {
  this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocus }));
};
```

to

```
onFocusChange(calendarFocus) {
  this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocus }));
};
```